# Creating a new hash with default keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a hash with an index that comes from an array.

```
ary = ["a", "b", "c"]
h = Hash.new(ary.each{|a| h[a] = 0})
```

My goal is to start with a hash like this:

```
h = {"a"=>0, "b"=>0, "c"=>0}
```

so that later when the hash has changed I can reset it with h.default

Unfortunately the way I'm setting up the hash is not working... any ideas?

Comment: Your code makes no sense, apparently you are mixing it up with the optional block that the hash constructor takes: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718.

Comment: For anyone still wondering after six years, the reason this doesn't work is that `Hash.new()` (along with `Hash.new {}`) isn't used this way; rather, it provides **default values** for when you try to access as-yet-undefined keys. `Hash[]` (the bare constructor, not the `::new` method) allows you to **convert an existing array to hash** (although it wouldn't accept an argument like this, either).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should instantiate your hash `h` first, and then fill it with the contents of the array:

```
h = {}    
ary = ["a", "b", "c"]
ary.each{|a| h[a] = 0}
```

Comment: why isn't it possible to combine the hash declaration with initializing the values, the way I tried to do?

Comment: I believe it's because the variable `h` is still nil when you try to access it in the each block. It's akin to saying `s = s + 4`, which will give you a NilClass error. What error did you get with your original implementation?

Answer (score 7):

Use the default value feature for the hash

```
h = Hash.new(0)

h["a"]      # => 0
```

In this approach, the key is not set.

```
h.key?("a") # => false
```

Other approach is to set the missing key when accessed.

```
h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = 0}
h["a"]      # => 0
h.key?("a") # => true
```

Even in this approach, the operations like `key?` will fail if you haven't accessed the key before.

```
h.key?("b") # => false
h["b"]      # => 0
h.key?("b") # => true
```

You can always resort to brute force, which has the least boundary conditions.

```
h = Hash.new.tap {|h| ["a", "b", "c"].each{|k| h[k] = 0}}
h.key?("b") # => true
h["b"]      # => 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this where you expand a list into zero-initialized values:

```
list = %w[ a b c ]

hash = Hash[list.collect { |i| [ i, 0 ] }]
```

You can also make a Hash that simply has a default value of 0 for any given key:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
```

Any new key referenced will be pre-initialized to the default value and this will avoid having to initialize the whole hash.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient way, but I always appreciate one-liners that reveal a little more about Ruby's versatility:

```
h =  Hash[['a', 'b', 'c'].collect { |v|  [v, 0] }]
```

Or another one-liner that does the same thing:

```
h = ['a', 'b', 'c'].inject({}) {|h, v| h[v] = 0; h }
```

By the way, from a performance standpoint, the one-liners run about 80% of the speed of:

```
h = {}
ary = ['a','b','c']
ary.each { |a| h[a]=0 }
```

Comment: No need for the old Hash[*(...)flatten] pattern, it's been a while Hash[...] takes also pairs.

Comment: Also, try benchmarking this versus McStretch's solution, I think you'll find that it's not worth the saved typing.

Comment: That's a given. One-liners are always more fun, though.

Comment: Bit nicer (I think) version of the inject one-liner: `array.inject({}) { |h, v| h.update(v => 0) }`

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 added `index_with` on `Enumerable` module. This will help in creating a hash from an enumerator with default or fetched values.

```
ary = %w[a b c]
hash = ary.index_with(0) # => {"a"=>0, "b"=>0, "c"=>0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `Enum#inject` method which I'm a fan of for its cleanliness. I haven't benchmarked it compared to the other options though.

```
h = ary.inject({}) {|hash, key| hash[key] = 0; hash}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way of having a hash with the keys actually added

```
Hash[[:a, :b, :c].zip([])] # => {:a=>nil, :b=>nil, :c=>nil}

Hash[[:a, :b, :c].zip(Array.new(3, 0))] # => {:a=>0, :b=>0, :c=>0}
```